# How do I list all channels a user in a Slack workspace is currently in?

Tags: slack

Is there a way (via client or API) to list all the channels a given user is currently in?  I do not see a way to view this information on their profile page in the desktop Slack client.

Alternatively, is there a way to list a user's channel join log/history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the list of channels a user is member of is not something you can do with the standard Slack client, but its rather easy to achieve with the web API. Here is my answer on the same question from stackoverflow: [Get list of channels a user is a member of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47774605/4379151).

Answer (score 6):

There is a way through the interface if you're a workspace admin.

1. Head over to "manage members" where you'll see a list of all members in your workspace.
2. From there, find the user that you're interested in and choose "Change account type".
3. Choose "Multi-channel guest" and press next.
4. You'll get a window showing all of the channels that the user belongs to.

Comment: This doesn't work if a member is already a multi-channel guest, however pressing "Edit info" in the user list will bring up a form that shows the user's channels among other things.